# excel vba IE clicking a button

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Through Excel and VBA, i am opening a [page.](https://dhli.dhl.com/dhli-client/shipmentair?3&shipmentId=151218573&accountGroup)

I want to click on the button 'Expand' through vba but I am getting an error.

I tried using both VBA commands listed below

```
Doc.getElementsByClassName("dhl-btn-main collapse-btn-expand-all")(0).Click
Doc.getElementsByClassName("dhl-btn-main collapse-btn-expand-all").Click
```

The error that I get is 
Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: I had IE8 , when i upgraded to IE10 it solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "Doc" is your reference to IE try this:

```
 Set ElementCol = Doc.document.getElementsByClassName("dhl-btn-main collapse-btn-expand-all")

 For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    btnInput.Click
 Next btnInput
```

---

**Working Example**:

```
Private Sub IE_Expand()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'IE.Visible = False

    IE.Navigate "https://dhli.dhl.com/dhli-client/shipmentair;jsessionid=q3tzTzyLcL7JkxkNQ4nv7Jtrpzk1glylCyJ7vJzT27h2xBG5zXSm!599496067?0&shipmentId=151218573&accountGroup"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    IE.Visible = True

    Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("dhl-btn-main collapse-btn-expand-all")

    ElementCol.Item(0).Click

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```