# VBA Clicking on an Item with Internet Exporer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web, screen-scraping

My company uses a web based reporting system and I'm trying to automatically export the data to Excel. There is a standard dropdown menu with File > Export to XLS and I would like to automatically click the "Export" button to download the report.

I have read through other posts dealing with clicking buttons to expand a page, or enter a value into a form, etc, but possibly because the button is in a drop down menu, or because the element is within an `iframe` none of the previously posted solutions have worked for me.

So Far:

- I can navigate to the page
- I can get the `menuExportXLS` element
- `Debug.print` prints the correct `innerText`
- My code is not throwing any errors

**BUT I can't successfully click the button to download the file.**

Alternatively, there is a javascript `onclick` script within the HTML that could trigger the download, but I don't know how to call it in VBA. I would be happy to get either method running.

[Sample of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a43C8.png)

```
Sub ExportXLSTest()

Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim Obj As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://Site"

With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Set Obj = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("menuExportXLS")
Debug.Print Obj.innerText
Obj.Click

Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel vba IE clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670379/excel-vba-ie-clicking-a-button). (If that one's not  suitable, the are numerous others, this is a very common question.)

Comment: You're getting the list item but the click handler is on the child `<a>` element. Maybe try 
 `Obj.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click`

Comment: Isn't [`InternetExplorerMedium`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/shdocvw.internetexplorermedium) a [tag:vb.net] object?

Comment: @Tim Williams I've tried this and unfortunately it doesn't get the element. I'm fairly sure that its because the element is within an `iframe`

Comment: @ashleedawg I'm not sure. If I create a new `internetExplorer.application` instead, I can't navigate to the site. From other posts, I gathered that problems are probably caused by IE running at a low integrity level by default, so `InternetExplorerMedium` fixed that part of my problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure being in a frame shouldn't have any impact - if you can get the list item you should be able to get to the link element from that...

Comment: Please don't use images of HTML but actually use the snippet tool to include HTML code. You make reference to an iframe but that is not visible within what you have shown. TimWilliams makes a valid point re the child a tag. If you can set Obj properly then Obj.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).FireEvent "onclick" should trigger the event.

Comment: @TimWilliams I misunderstood your comment the first time I read it. Your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector to target the element;

```
appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[onclick*='exportXLS']").Click
```

This is an attribute = value selector that targets the first element in the content document that has an `onclick` attribute containing the value `exportXLS`.