# VBA: Go to IE site and tick by element

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

New to navigating with IE. I m trying to go to a site `https://www.thetrainline.com/` and tick the `Return` button by using element `getElementsByID("return").FirstChild.Click` However all this does is bring up the site. It doesn't tick the return option.

Any ideas?

```
Public Function GetHTML() As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorEscape

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim HTML As Object
    Dim myElement As Object

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.thetrainline.com/"

    IE.navigate URL
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    MsgBox ("IE Loaded")

    Set myElement = IE.getElementsByID("return").FirstChild.Click

    Exit Function

ErrorEscape:
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set HTML = Nothing

End Function
```

P.S. I want many users to be able to use this without having to download something. Hence, why I am not using Selenium.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting an error on the `Set myElement =` line?  I would think `Click` isn't returning anything.

Comment: Use a timeout to detect that the site is "loaded" is not the way to do it. The IE has events to tell that a page is really  loaded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299134/failproof-wait-for-ie-to-load. And second getElementById is a function which depends on a DOCUMENT. So get first the document before you fire up this.

Comment: Thanks both, @ThomasLudewig. So if I don't have a document. But I just want to simply click on the box and select it?

Comment: Maybee you will ahve a look at the acc. Javascript function ;) If you get a element with the document.getElementById function you can now do a .click(). you has also a typo in IE.getElement>>>s<<<ByID("return").FirstChild.Click. ById can only retunr a single element. so it should look mo like  -> var doc: doc = ie.getdocument : var elm : elm=doc.getElementByID("return").FirstChild : elm.click().

Comment: There are numerous samples on this site.  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22670379/5162073).

Comment: It is simply ie.document.getElementById("return").click but you need a proper page load wait before and possibly a timed loop for the element to be present. There are examples of both on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify your code to click on 'return' radio button.

Modified code:

```
Sub demo()
 Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim HTML As Object
    Dim myElement As Object

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.thetrainline.com/"
IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate URL
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    'MsgBox ("IE Loaded")

    IE.document.getElementById("return").Click

ErrorEscape:
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set HTML = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]